# RenderTarget2D not preserving transparent background

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I'm working on a project.  All 2D using spriteBatch.

I'm having things like explosions use custom effects that do not apply to the rest of the image.  So here is my flow so far:

1)Clear the Background

2)Draw all the explosion sprites

3)Capture that image and implement my effects into a separate RenderTarget2D

4)Draw my Background

5)Draw the RenderTarget2D created in step 3

6) Draw everything else

The problem I'm running into is the RenderTarget2D created is not transparent in the areas not drawn on.  As a result, the background drawn in step 4 is not shown.

I have tried GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent) following any calls to SetRenderTarget(null).  However, I am still getting that purple background.

Any ideas?

I'd post code, but there's too much for you all to have to parse through.

Answer (score 0):

if you follow this flow it should work;

```
    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(renderTarget);
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent);
    // Draw stuff to texture
    GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

    GraphicsDevice.Clear(BackgroundColor);  // Important to clear here
    // Draw background
    // Draw texture
    // Draw stuff
```